# 404 Not Found - category-selector.css file

Tags: magento2, css, frontend-error, http-error-404

I have been trying to locate a copy of `category-selectory.css` that has gone missing from my store and causing problems with Google Shopping extension.

Does anyone have any idea if this file was removed in Magento 2.1.9 or still have a copy that they could post?

The file should be located here:

```
<css src="Magento_Catalog::catalog/category-selector.css"/>
```

But it giving a 404 error!

Comment: Have you tried doing a static content deploy?

Comment: Yes for adminhtml but I still get the error do you have the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file can be found here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/magento/magento2/2.0/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/adminhtml/web/catalog/category-selector.css

Between release 2.0 and 2.1 the file disappears from the repository, so I imagine it's been deprecated in favor of a different solution.